# newline parameter not working as expected

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to write a csv file (Python 3.8) using newlines = "". However, every time I run my program, the first row gets overwritten. My code is as follows:

```
def write_csv():
    with open("asco.csv", 'w', newline = '') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([full_name, credentials])
```

This gets called every time I collect new data for these variables. Each time new variables are created and this is called, it gets rewritten. I also create a header for the file using the following code, before I execute what I do above.

```
with open("asco.csv", 'w', newline = '') as file: #create file 
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Name","Credentials"])
```

Any idea what is causing this issue? Everything I have read says that newline = '' should fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in 'append' mode:

```
with open("asco.csv", 'a', newline = '') as file: #create file 
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Name","Credentials"])
```

If you open it in 'write' mode, you erase the file each time, essentially only writing whatever the last thing was your program ran. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second
>   argument is another string containing a few characters describing the
>   way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will
>   only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same
>   name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data
>   written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the
>   file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r'
>   will be assumed if it’s omitted.

Comment: No worries, it's not really obvious that it does that, I just happened to go through that tutorial today so I remembered.